# getting a line from a file and then reading word by word. C++

Tags: c++, string, cpu-word

I have a trie and want to search number of common words in each line of a txt file.
I use getline to get the line but unable to proceed.

I tried

```
 string s;
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("user.txt");
    getline(myfile,s);
    string person(s);
    istringstream iss(person);
    do
    {
       string sub;
       iss >> sub;
       cout << sub << endl;
     } while (iss);
```

but it says 
 'std::istringstream iss' has initializer but incomplete type

Comment: You don't have to go line by line if you want to process words. It makes things more complicated, as you see, you used a stringstream. Why not read directly from the file like `myfile >> sub`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <sstream>      // std::istringstream 

std::string s;
std::ofstream myfile("user.txt");
std::getline(myfile, s);
std::istringstream iss(s);
std::string sub;

while(iss >> sub)
{
   cout << sub << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to `#include <sstream>`.